# I am using WPF Toolkit to print a graph and The x axis is all smeared

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit

I am using WPF Toolkit to print a graph. Here how it's look like:

The x axis is all smeared. How can i change x axis? for example axis with 5 unit interval.

Here is my code:

**c# code**:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("AnaloguData.txt");
List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> valueList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>();

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    if(i %370==0)
{
    string[] words = lines[i].Split('\t');
    valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>(words[0].ToString(), Convert.ToDouble(words[1])));
}

lineChart.DataContext = valueList;
```

**xaml code**:

```
<Grid Height="921">
    <chartingToolkit:Chart  Name="lineChart" Title="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="254" Margin="0,0,-110,0">
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries   DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSelectionEnabled="True"  Margin="0,0,2,0"/>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
<Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code to edit axis properties. (Note , I have used  "charting" as namespace" instead of "chartingToolkit" )

```
       <Grid>
           <charting:Chart  Name="lineChart" Title="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="254" Margin="0,0,-110,0">
        <charting:LineSeries   DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSelectionEnabled="True"  Margin="0,0,2,0"/>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>

                <charting:Chart.Title>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Chart_Title"  FontStyle="Normal" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Ergebnisse"  ></TextBlock>
                </charting:Chart.Title>

                    <charting:Chart.Axes>
                    <charting:LinearAxis FontWeight="SemiBold"  Orientation="X" >
                        <charting:LinearAxis.Title>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="X_Axis" Margin="0,5,0,0" FontStyle="Normal" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Abgewickelte Länge in  mm"  ></TextBlock>
                        </charting:LinearAxis.Title>
                    </charting:LinearAxis>

                    <charting:LinearAxis    Orientation="Y" >
                        <charting:LinearAxis.Title>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Y_Axis" Margin="0,0,0,5"  FontStyle="Normal" Text="Ausgewertete Größe" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold"  ></TextBlock>
                        </charting:LinearAxis.Title>

                    </charting:LinearAxis>
                </charting:Chart.Axes>
            </charting:Chart>

            </Grid>
```